# Why isn't my class method's if statements not modifying the private variables time variables

Tags: c++, class

this is basically a time program that supposed to output well... the time (from an input). It supposed to have overflow checkers that basically check whether or not minutes/seconds are above 60 and then add 1 to either int minutes or int hours. Currently, it's not wanting to do that and outputs 'Time : 1:3:13' which isn't correct.

```
class Time {
    private:
        int seconds;
        int minutes;
        int hours;

        Time() {

            hours = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            seconds = 0;

        }
    
    public: 

        Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {

            add(hours, minutes, seconds);

        }

        void add(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
        
            int secOverflow = (int)floor(seconds / 60);
            int minOverflow = (int)floor(minutes / 60);
            
            if (seconds > 60) {

             this->minutes += secOverflow;

            }

            this->seconds = seconds % 60;

            if (minutes > 60) {
            
             this->hours += minOverflow;
            
            }

            this->minutes = minutes % 60;
            
            this->hours = hours % 24;

        }

        void printTime() {
        
            std::cout << "Time : " << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << std::endl;
        
        }


    };


    int main() {
    
        Time Clock(28, 70, 80); // should result 05:11:20

        Clock.add(25, 63, 73); 

        Clock.printTime();

        return 0;
    
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems you wanted to use `+=` instead of `=+` (combination of `=` and `+`)

Comment: I changed it, same output

Comment: Why the result should be `11:17:33`?

Comment: Check all of your operators. You calculate minutes `this->minutes += secOverflow;`, but then override it with `this->seconds = seconds % 60;`. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: realising its a personal mathematical error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Division between integers are truncated, so you don't need `floor`.
- `=+` is combination of `=` and `+`. To assign result of addition, `+=` should be used.
- Assignment will eliminate what is previously assigned, so addition should be done after assignments.

Try this:

```
        void add(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            this->seconds = seconds % 60;
            int minutes_temp = minutes + seconds / 60;
            this->minutes = minutes_temp % 60;
            this->hours = (hours + minutes_temp / 60) % 24;
        }
```

(This function looks like `set` more than `add`, but I'll respect original name now)

Or if you want to actually add time:

```
        void add(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            int seconds_temp = this->seconds + seconds;
            int minutes_temp = this->minutes + minutes + seconds_temp / 60;
            int hours_temp = this->hours + hours + minutes_temp / 60;
            this->seconds = seconds_temp % 60;
            this->minutes = minutes_temp % 60;
            this->hours = hours_temp % 24;
        }
```

In this case, now the constructor

```
        Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {

            add(hours, minutes, seconds);

        }
```

will do addition without initialization of the members.

The members can be initialized using delegating constructors like this:

```
        Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) : Time() {

            add(hours, minutes, seconds);

        }
```

Now the result is `Time : 7:15:33` and this looks reasonable for me. I didn't understand why the result should be `11:17:33`.

Comment: Most likely a mathematical error on my part